# What does the subscript number on the Sekonic L-478D display mean?

Tags: light-meter

This is my first spot meter so please forgive my ignorance.
What is the sub-scripted number value next to the F-Stop value (below, and to the right)?

[image: Sekonic L-478D with subscript f-stop]

I've read through the manual over and over, and it really isn't clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read the shutter speed from my light meter?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59277/how-do-i-read-the-shutter-speed-from-my-light-meter)

Comment: This seems like an exact duplicate of the other question, even if its title is not very obvious — and the implication is that the, accepted answer to the other question is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subscripted number is showing the measured value in ¹⁄₁₀ -stop increments above displayed F-number. So for instance, in the manual when it shows **5.6<sub>7</sub>**, it is telling you that it measured ⁷⁄₁₀ stop above f/5.6, which comes out to approximately f/7.1 (5.6 * (√2)<sup>.7</sup> ≈ 7.14).

See also:

- [How do I read the shutter speed from my light meter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59277/how-do-i-read-the-shutter-speed-from-my-light-meter)
- "[Sekonic L-758DR Question](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2908910)" thread at dpreview.com
- "[Sekonic L-508 - 1/10 f-stops?](http://www.largeformatphotography.info/forum/showthread.php?44680-Sekonic-L-508-1-10-f-stops) thread at largeformatphotography.info